# What would the multifunctional inverse of $F(x)=|x|$ be?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, inverse, absolute-value, multivalued-functions

What would the multifunctional inverse of $F(x)=|x|$ be, assuming $x$ is on the complex plane. Also, how would this usually be represented? Note that this won't be a '*true*' function. (But assume a multivalued function is considered a function for simplicity's sake.)

Comment: Perhaps in more standard terms, one might notice that the *preimage* (or, in this case, fiber) $F^{-1}(r)$ is a circle of radius $r$ about the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F^{-1}(r) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=r\}$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $F^{-1}(z) = \emptyset$ for $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus\mathbb{R}^+$.